# Parse inner array with GSON, From API JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

So I would like to parse the json I get from an api with GSON. all the examples are very clear and I got it working perfectly. But now the API gave me somthing like this. Just making a class for the items with in the second curly braces doesn't work, see below.

So my question is does anyone have an idea how to make this work??

**SOLUTION:**

Stored this locally, member.json

```
{"Peter":{"id":585897,"name":"PhPeter","profileIconId":691,"age":99,"email":"peter@adress.com "}}
```

Class, Member.java

```
package JsonPackage;

public class Summoner {

    int id;  
    String name;  
    int profileIconId;
    int summonerLevel;
    long revisionDate;

    //getters setters  

    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    } 

    public int getProfileIconId() {  
        return profileIconId;  
    }  

    public int getSummonerLevel() {  
        return summonerLevel;  
    }  

    public long getRevisionDate() {  
        return revisionDate;  
    }  
}
```

Main class, MemberRead2Java.java:

```
package JsonPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ReadSummonerObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();  

        try {  

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\member.json"));  //path to your file


            Object obj = gson.fromJson(br, Object.class);
            if (obj instanceof Map) {
                Map map = (Map) obj;
                Collection coll = map.values();
                Iterator iter = coll.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Object str = iter.next();

                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(str.toString());
                    Summoner summonerObj = gson.fromJson(sr, Summoner.class);
                    System.out.println("Id: " + summonerObj.getId());
                    System.out.println("Name: " +summonerObj.getName());
                    System.out.println("ProfileIconID: " + summonerObj.getProfileIconId());
                    System.out.println("SummonerLevel: " + summonerObj.getSummonerLevel());
                    System.out.println("RevisionDate: " + summonerObj.getRevisionDate());
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't it work? What did the error message say?

Comment: You know, it's not necessary or reasonable to map every JSON string to a POJO.

Comment: Please provide necessary details. What is that you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

Basically you'll get a map for your input `( a key-value pair, in your case key is "Peter" and value is your Member object details)`, so you have to iterate over the map values , (where map values are your Member objects) and just convert the Strings to Member objects.

here I've used the StringReader (just read the json from the string) instead of the BufferedReader (reading from the .json file).

```
public static void main(String[] args)   {

String json ="{\"Peter\":{\"id\":585897,\"name\":\"PhPeter\",\"profileIconId\":691,\"age\":99,\"email\":\"peter@adress.com \"}}";
Gson gson = new Gson();  
StringReader reader = new StringReader(json);
   //convert the json string back to object  
Object obj = gson.fromJson(reader, Object.class);  
if(obj instanceof Map){
    Map map =(Map)obj;
    Collection coll = map.values();
    Iterator iter = coll.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
         Object str = iter.next();

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(str.toString());
        Member memberObj = gson.fromJson(sr, Member.class); 
     System.out.println("Id: " + memberObj.getId());  
     System.out.println("Name: " + memberObj.getName());  
     System.out.println("ProfileIconID: " + memberObj.getProfileIconId());  
     System.out.println("Age: " + memberObj.getAge());  
     System.out.println("Email: " + memberObj.getEmail());  
    }

}

    }
```

**Edit:**
Here is another version reading from file.Just replace the main method with the following, make sure the FileReader path is correct:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Member.json"));

            Object obj = gson.fromJson(br, Object.class);
            if (obj instanceof Map) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) obj;
            Collection<Object> coll = map.values();
            Iterator<Object> iter = coll.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Object str = iter.next();

                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(str.toString());
                    Member memberObj = gson.fromJson(sr, Member.class);
                    System.out.println("Id: " + memberObj.getId());
                    System.out.println("Name: " + memberObj.getName());
                    System.out.println("ProfileIconID: "
                            + memberObj.getProfileIconId());
                    System.out.println("Age: " + memberObj.getAge());
                    System.out.println("Email: " + memberObj.getEmail());
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

prints:

```
Id: 585897
Name: PhPeter
ProfileIconID: 691
Age: 99
Email: peter@adress.com
```

**For what you have asked in comments:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();  

        try {   

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Members.json"));  //path to your file


            Object obj = gson.fromJson(br, Object.class);
            if (obj instanceof Map) {
                Map map = (Map) obj;
                Collection coll = map.values();    
                Iterator iter = coll.iterator();
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {

                    Object str = iter.next();
                  JsonArray jsonArr = parser.parse(str.toString()).getAsJsonArray();
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.size();i++){

                    Member memberObj = gson.fromJson(jsonArr.get(i).toString(), Member.class);
                    System.out.println("Id: " + memberObj.getId());
                    System.out.println("Name: " +memberObj.getName());
                    System.out.println("ProfileIconID: " + memberObj.getProfileIconId());
                    System.out.println("Email: " + memberObj.getEmail());
                    System.out.println("Age: " + memberObj.getAge());
                    }
                } 

            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I got it to work perfectly. The reason I didn't react is that I'm pretty knew to java and wanted to do one thing at the time. It works, but I don't know what it does in de first part of the if statement. BTW I get 3 warnings about the types map, collections and Iterator. Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized.

Comment: @PHPeter, Ok, basically instead of mapping to Member.java, your json is in a format of a java.util.Map (basically map is a collection of key-value pairs). So your member object will be a value in the map. so You have to iterate over map values and map it to the Member.java, hope it is clear. let me know if you want more explanation. In this case you can ignore warnings :)

Comment: @PHPeter, could you please accept the solution if it worked for you. :)

Comment: Thanks to your answer I got it working, but whatif I had something like this: `{"Members":[{"id":585897,"name":"PhPeter","profileIconId":691,"age":99,"email":‌​"peter@adress.com"},{"id":645231,"name":"Bill","profileIconId":123,"age":56,"emai‌​l":"bill@adress.com"}]}`

Comment: @PHPeter, please see my edited answer, now you'll be having a json array as your value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an inner array, GSON expects this inner array as an inner class and since it doesn't find one, it is likely throwing errors. Create your member class as follows:

```
class Member {

    String member_name; // To hold the member name in the outer array
    Details details; // You need an existing instance to parse the data into. I missed this.

    // Inner class corresponding to inner array
    public static class Details {
        int id;
        String name;
        int profileIconId;
        int age;
        String email;
        // Getters and setters for inner class
    }
    // Getters and setters for outer class
    public Details getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }
    // Other getters and setters
}
```

Construct your member object from this class and reference it as you usually would with static nested classes.

```
Member memberObj = gson.fromJson(br, Member.class);
```

To access methods from your inner class, simply do the following:
    // See how I am now accessing an existing instance rather than creating a new instance
    // I was thinking on the fly and forgot about this
    Member.Details details = memberObj.getDetails();
    String item = details.getterMethodForItem();

Comment: I understand how to modify the member class. But how do i call the getter methode from the inner class?

Comment: @PHPeter - can you please see the edit on how to access inner class methods

Comment: I tried what you suggested, see my edit of the original post but it prints: "Id: 0" which should be: "Id: 585897" Where am I going wrong

Comment: You should be using System.out.println("Id:" + item); and that should be it. I'm not sure why you're trying to convert the primitive type int back to json in that step. Can you just use the statement that I showed and see what you get.

Comment: First off, ty for your time. But sorry, you lost me. I just copy/paste your statement (see post), but I get the same result: Ïd: 0". That is because I never use the memberObj. Maybe you can edit my post and show me what you mean.

Comment: Hey.. can you check my edited answer. I was originally trying to create a new object while I should have had an existing instance. That was my error. Let me know how this goes - it worked for me. I also made the change to your source code but it needs to be reviewed before the changes show up.

Comment: For some reason your edit got rejected. So I changed it to what you suggested. But I get an error (see first post) ln 24 -> "int item = details.getId();" I guess it’s because the output of details is null, (see comments)